Newtonsoft: How to find self-referencing loop?
I'm getting an error when I attempt to serialize an object:

Self referencing loop detected with type 'Namespace.MyClass'. Path ''.

I understand what this error means. Somewhere in my class, I have a loop where ClassA references ClassB, and ClassB references ClassA, resulting in an infinite loop that Newtonsoft cannot resolve.
There are countless questions on this site about this error.  I know that I can ignore the properties with ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore. But that's not my question.
My question is this: how do I actually find the reference loop, so I can try to fix the underlying class?
My class is quite large, and extends classes from a library that I do not control. However, objects of the library classes have serialized just fine in the past, so it shouldn't be the library causing the problem. But the actual exception doesn't give me any useful information of which properties of my class are self-referencing.
Is there a way to detect this? Or do I just have to dig through my code manually?

The Path '' should contain the path of the loop, it's strange that it's empty...

sounds like an exercise in reflection + finding cycles in a graph

Serializing huge random object graphs of classes you don't control sounds like a bit of a disaster whatever you do. Serialization can be so finicky sometimes, it's nice to keep full control.

@user246821 I'm asking if, given the fact that Newtonsoft clearly used some sort of automated process to detect the loop, if there's a way to get it to tell me where it detected the loop, instead of just saying it found it somewhere.  The error I have right now basically says "I found a problem but I'm not telling you where".

@Charlieface 100% agree.  Unfortunately, that's how Quartz.net works.  I'm trying to work within the bounds of the system I'm using.

Json.NET throws a "Self referencing loop" exception when, in the course of serializing an instance of some type, an attempt is made to recursively serialize the exact same instance (using the default equality comparer to check for identical instances).  When this happens, to prevent a StackOverflowException, Json.NET will throw a JsonSerializationException to abort serialization.  Its message will indicate where the exception occurs.  These messages consist of two parts, and will look something like one of the following:

Self referencing loop detecfor property '{Property}' with type '{Type}'. Path '{Path}'.

or

Self referencing loop detected with type '{Type}. Path '{Path}'.

Let's break these down.  Firstly, the type and (optionally) the property indicate the exact POCO type and (optionally) property that caused the problem.  For instance,  when serializing the following types:
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass Myself => this;
}

public class MyFieldClass
{
    public MyFieldClass() => this.Myself = this;
    public MyFieldClass Myself;
}

Json.NET will throw the following exceptions

Self referencing loop detected for property 'Myself' with type 'MyClass'.
Self referencing loop detected for property 'Myself' with type 'MyFieldClass'.

However, your exception message does not indicate any property.  This indicates the self-referencing loop was generated from something other than a property, which can include:

A self-referencing enumerable, for instance:
var list = new List<object>();
list.Add(list);


A JsonConverter that attempts to perform a recursive serialization that would result in a stack overflow, for instance:
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]
public record MyConvertable;

public class MyConverter : JsonConverter<MyConvertable>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, MyConvertable? value, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value); // HERE
    public override MyConvertable? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, MyConvertable? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}



In both of the above cases Json.NET will tell you the type being serialized without mentioning a property:

Self referencing loop detected with type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'.
Self referencing loop detected with type 'MyConvertable'.

Secondly, the path.  This JSONPath value indicates where in the JSON file being written that the loop was encountered, more precisely the value of JsonWriter.ContainerPath at the point the exception was thrown.  This is where in the serialization graph the exception was thrown, but will not include the current property being written.
A path value of '' indicates the root object.
Thus your message:

Self referencing loop detected with type 'Namespace.MyClass'. Path ''.

Indicates that, while serializing the root object MyClass, an attempt to serialize the same object was made but not as a field or property value.  Since the class name doesn't sound like a collection, I'd guess it was due to some converter attempting to recursively serialize the object itself.
Alternatively, you could always attach a debugger and break when a  JsonSerializationException is thrown by CheckForCircularReference().  The object? value and JsonProperty? property arguments should indicate what caused the problem.
Demo fiddle here.
